# Why does my high memory requiring code work on MacOS but not Linux when Linux box has more memory?

Tags: c, linux, macos, gcc, clang

So I have a program which requires a significant amount of memory and needs to allocate a (sparse) 600 000 x 600 000 integer array. Although I believe that this can be improved with regard to space and memory requirements, I am unable to run this on my machine (Manjaro Linux x86_64) with 40gb of memory while my superior is able to run it on his machine with 16gb of memory and on MacOS (64 bit). When running on my machine the program runs until it tries to `malloc` that array and then the program is killed.

As for more information, I have double checked and this is exactly the same code and we are compiling it exactly the same way. That being said, the output of `gcc -v` for me is:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++,d --with-isl --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-install-libiberty --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-multilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-werror gdc_include_dir=/usr/include/dlang/gdc
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.2.0 (GCC)
```

By contrast, the output on my superior's computer is:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode/app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread mode: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Please let me know if there is any more relevant information I can provide.

---

The relavent lines are:

```cpp
int **Idx;
Idx = (int **)malloc(Num_Idx*sizeof(*Idx));
for (i = 0; i < Num_Idx; i++)
      Idx[i] = (int *)malloc(Num_Idx*sizeof(*Idx[i]));
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Consider using [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on Linux. See [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Comment: @StephenNewell The program gets killed, memory is usually at around 90% when that happens. May actually be higher.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that is an interesting idea. I will do that!

Comment: Just to clarify... your program needs 1.5TB of memory... (assuming 4 bytes per integer x 600K  x 600K matrix member count)?....  sounds like maybe an in-memory structure isn't what you would really desire. No matter which machine you're using, you will need enough disk space for memory swapping and that's a lot of performance overhead.

Comment: Also read [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) and [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html)

Comment: @Myst in theory yes. However, it somehow is able to run with <16 gb. I assume this is due to overpromising by the kernel? (very possibly incorrect. Lower level programming is something i've gotten into recently

Comment: See [this related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441364/what-is-the-purpose-of-memory-overcommitment-on-linux)

Comment: @HonoredTarget , I assume you realize that with a 1.5TB memory allocation the OS will have to use [memory mapping / swap file techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging). Your 16Gb / 64Gb memory situation doesn't really matter all that much in this situation.... the "memory" won't be allocated on the RAM anyway.

Comment: @HonoredTarget "In theory, yes" - no, when you have 1.5TB array, there's no theory there - you *need* that much disk for swapping. It might appear to work on MacOS due to overcommit - but soon, it'll break. This is not a Linux vs. MacOS problem - it's your program.

Comment: @Myst I think use `mmap` for other parts of the program. However I don't think he has 1.5 TB of memory? I am rerunning to double check the 600,000 figure was right but I don't think it allocates everything (even backed up by a file?)

Comment: @P.P Agreed. I inherited this program and want to eventually significantly decrease the size of the array after I get an initial run done. It should end up being 600,000 x 2 but I want to try and get the output to work on my machine. This is only using the first two chromosomes (why the data is so large) but I need to try and get it to run at a larger scale before I start fixing it.

Comment: The difference between 1.5TB and 5Mb (i.e., between a 2D integer matrix of 600K x 600K members v.s a 2D integer matrix of 600K x 2 members) is huge. The two programs might not resemble each other in any way. Also remember, if you're loading the data set from somewhere, that original dataset also takes room. A 1.5TB dataset requires at least 3TB of space (original + copy)... which touches on [Big Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data) programming techniques. a 5Mb dataset can live in the RAM, a 1.5TB dataset doesn't even fit on many consumer level hard drives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Linux docs on overcommit](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting) with emphasis:

> The Linux kernel supports the following overcommit handling modes
>
> 0 -   Heuristic overcommit handling. **Obvious overcommits of
> address space are refused**. Used for a typical system. It
> ensures a seriously wild allocation fails while allowing
> overcommit to reduce swap usage.  root is allowed to
> allocate slightly more memory in this mode. **This is the
> default.**
>
> 1  -   Always overcommit. Appropriate for some scientific
> applications. **Classic example is code using sparse arrays**
> and just relying on the virtual memory consisting almost
> entirely of zero pages.
>
> (...)

You can change to mode #1 with `sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1`

Comment: This will work as long as the CPU supports at least a 41-bit virtual address size.  Most x86-64 CPUs support 48 bits, but some other processors literally cannot handle address spaces that large.

Comment: @bk2204 I think that may be the issue. I realized that it was saying the matrix was actually 1107406 x 1107406.. however it does seem like it still got killed. Not sure if this change worked?

Comment: I can `malloc(1107406l*1107406*8);` just fine with this setting. Are you sure it's still the malloc that's failing?

Comment: Hmm. You are right... time to run the code for another couple of hours to figure out where it dies :)

Comment: Hmm. The code ran and it got killed just as I tried to malloc. Starts at ~50% memory and then shoots up to 90 and then gets killed.

Comment: Hmm. Still having issues. Is is possibly the way allocated the memory (see code in edited post)?